# Have issue in get current user's location with my app on ios 6

Tags: iphone, core-location, locationmanager, ios6

My application is running fine on iOS 5, I get the normal user's location information. But when installing my app on iOS 6, my application can not get the user's location (I don't have the popup asking permission location, and in location services I don't have the icon of my app. Other apps like `Instagram` and `Path` have the icon of the app in the location services on iOS 6). When I use this code below to check this issue, `NSlog` shows: `Unable to determine, possibly not available`

I don't understand why this is the case. I've tried other apps like Instagram or Path. We still get the normal user's location. I studied iOS 6 change method delegate in `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, but I think that's not the reason because my application does not ask the permission to get the user's location.

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
        switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"We have access to location services");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"Location services denied by user");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"Parental controls restrict location services");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"Unable to determine, possibly not available");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Location Services Are Disabled");
    }
```

Comment: Anyone help, I desperately needed to solve this problem.
Thanks you so much

Comment: Maybe my application there is a conflict with ios6?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. For my app this situation was generated because I check if locationServices is enabled and I start update location only if this is true ([self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation].)

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled {
    if (([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) && ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    } 
}
```

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation] without the check looks fine, but it's possible to generate other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you just check if location is available, but do not use it. So iOS never asks for permission, because it isn't used.
Your check is working fine!

Use a tutorial like [this one](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) and it will work. So did I resolve it for me!